# Trying to understand how horizontal forms work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h5>Some text
    </h5>
    <hr />

    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I understand that when the browser view port is medium or larger, the label will appear on the same line as the associated control. What I don't understand is why, when the view port is small or xs, does the form revert to a vertical form? I'm not specifically telling it to do this. Is this just default bootstrap behavior? Also, if I were to remove all the col-md-2 and col-md-10 classes, the form **always** displays as a vertical form. Why?

Comment: FYI, if you're asking an HTML or CSS question, it's usually better to show the actual HTML that's output to the browser, not your un-compiled source-code. Only show the source if that's what you're asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this just default bootstrap behavior?

Yes. As the screen gets smaller, the layout collapses to make it fit.

> Also, if I were to remove all the col-md-2 and col-md-10 classes, the form always displays as a vertical form. Why?

Bootstrap 3 is a mobile-first layout framework. The default layout is vertical, so it will fit on a mobile-sized screen. The `-md-` bit of `col-md-2` means "medium sized screen" (by default that's 992px wide and upwards). So `.col-md-2` means "2 (out of 12) columns on a medium-sized screen".

You can add more classes (e.g. `col-sm-2`, `col-xs-2` and `col-lg-2` for small, xtra-small and large screens) to adjust your layout for other screen sizes.

Go and have a good read of http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid and play with [the examples](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples). It tells you everything you need to know.

Comment: Technically, `.col-md-2` is "medium (or larger) sized screen". `.col-md-2.col-lg-2` would be completely redundant.